# Dynamic PHP images

Tags: php, html, image, dynamic

I was looking through posts about modifying/packaging images in PHP and can't seem to find anything. What I'm trying to do is have an image template that I can modify by $_GETting a variable.

For instance: http://foo.bar/image.php?content=Monday

If we were then to wrap the above in an  tag, it would show as "You have been invited to a party on Monday!" (Something to that effect)

Basically:

- Set template
- One or two words changed on said template
- Auto-resize to fit a page

If anyone could provide a link to a library that does this, or provide a code example, that would be great.

Comment: why you don't use scripted SVG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might want to take at this page from PHP.net -> https://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples-png.php

Answer (score 1):

You can generate images in PHP using Cairo, ImageMagick or GD. There's a wealth of documentation on PHP's site: http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php

Note that not every API/function library is available on every system. I remember even a few years ago that ImageMagick and GD were hard to get working on non-Linux systems. I don't know how it is today though.